# Only zoom certain elements inside of ScrollView in React Native

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I am attempting to implement a cropping tool with pinch zoom in React Native. The cropping works fine, but I am having trouble zooming the image while my overlay is on top of it.

Code:

```
     <ScrollView
     maximumZoomScale={2}
     minimumZoomScale={1}
     scrollEnabled={false}
     bouncesZoom={false}>

      <Animated.View 
        style={this.getStyles()}
         {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}>
           <View>
              <Image style={[{height: getCropContainerHeight(),
               width: this.getCropContainerWidth()}]} 
               source={{uri: this.props.image}} />
           </View>
      </Animated.View>

      <Overlay movement={{...this._panResponder.panHandlers}} />

  </ScrollView>
```

If the Overlay is inside of the Scrollview, then both the overlay and the image get zoomed in. If the Overlay is outside of the ScrollView then of course the Image does not zoom.

[Here is what my app looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXgSq.jpg)

Any thoughts on how can I zoom in on ONLY the image, without affecting the overlay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the ScrollView to handle the touch events, you can place the overlay outside of the ScrollView, position it on top of the ScrollView using `position: relative` or `position: absolute`, and give the overlay root view a [pointerEvents](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#pointerevents) prop of `"none"`.

This way the overlay won't capture the touches.

Comment: Wow, that did it. I have been stuck on this for days, Thank you so much!